# Route Model Binding working in Laravel 5.3 without changes in RouteServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following the laravel 5 tutorial, in laracasts, by Jeffrey Way. In a Lesson called Route Model Binding, I have changed the methods edit, update and show parameters to Article `$article`. And now Route Model Binding is working. But I don't change anything in **RouteServiceProvider.php**. Does laravel a made implicit binding in my case, only reading the parameter Article `$article`? I'm using laravel 5.3.

Before(edit method)

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
   return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
}
```

After

```
public function edit(Article $article)
{
   return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is implicit model binding.